# Runtime Analysis: What grows faster?

Tags: time-complexity

I was wondering which runtime is a tight upper bound for $f(n,m)= n^2 + 1/2^k$ with $k = n - m$

Intuitively I thought that $f(n,m)$ is in $O(n^2)$ but the longer I am thinking about this the more I tend to say that $f(n,m)$ is in $O(2^k)$.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is $n \geq m $?

Comment: yes n is indeed larger or equal m!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $k=n-m \ge 0$ you have that $n^2 < f(n,m) \le n^2 + (1/2)^0 = n^2+1$, showing that $f(n,m) \in \Theta(n^2)$.